# Thunderstorms in the Canadian Rockies in September?

Tags: weather, canada, rocky-mountains

How frequent are 
thunderstorms in the Canadian Rockies in September?

[Canadian Climate Normals](http://climate.weather.gc.ca/climate_normals/results_e.html?stnID=2409&prov=&lang=e&dCode=4&dispBack=1&StationName=Lake_Louise&SearchType=Contains&province=ALL&provBut=&month1=0&month2=12) do not list thunderstorm frequency.

Answer (score 3):

[Rainfall in Banff/Lake Louise is pretty low in September](http://www.infobanff.com/info/?i=aw). Thunderstorms are much rarer in the Canadian Rockies than in the rest of Canada. I've lived in Banff for six years and there have only been thunderstorms three times in that period. That said, avoid high mountain-exposure in the event of a thunderstorm.

It's pretty much guaranteed to snow at least once in September, especially at altitude. It never stays though, usually either a dusting or a few centimetres that melt within 48 hrs.  I've seen it happen in the first week of Sept and be 20c two weeks later.

Comment: I don't mind a bit of snow (as long as it's not more than a dm or so), but I'm scared of thunderstorms, in particular in exposed places such as the Skyline Trail.

Comment: June rainy some thunderstorms, July thunderstorms with large hail (more so in the eastern foothills), August Early September less likely. Long Range September and October will be warmer and drier than normal. http://www.almanac.com/weather/longrange/AB/Banff